# How to prevent QScroller gesture from interfering with QGraphicsView drag mode?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qgraphicsview, qscrollarea

I am developing a touchscreen compatible app that has some widgets that contain `QScrollAreas`. I am using

`QScroller::grabGesture(ui->scrollArea->viewport(), QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);`

to allow the user to easily scroll these widgets by swiping.

However, some of the scroll areas contain subclassed `QGraphicsViews`. I am adding `QGraphicsItems` to these and would like the user to be able to select items using rubberbanding. I have set the drag mode using
`setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag)`.

This works as desired if I don't also use `grabGesture` on the scroll area containing the view.
However, grabbing the gesture for the swipe scrolling interferes with the rubberbanding action of the graphics view.

How can I scroll widgets containing these views while also keeping the rubberbanding functionality in tact? I essentially want the widget to scroll unless the user is swiping inside of a `QGraphicsView`.